# How to update Firefox addon to accommodate a `Services module` replacement?

Tags: firefox-addon

Mozilla Validator just reported to me:

> E4X Deprecated/Removed
>
> Error: It is no longer possible to pass E4X objects between most
>   contexts, including different chrome windows or JS modules. E4X will
>   be completely removed by Gecko 20 (or possibly earlier). See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X for more information.

Now, the error is on this line:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
const XUL = Namespace("xul", "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
```

Mozilla Validator points to a [page that proposes this as a solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X):

> Warning: E4X is obsolete. It has been disabled by default for webpages
>   (content) in Firefox 17, disabled by default for chrome in Firefox 20,
>   and will be removed in Firefox 21. Use DOMParser/DOMSerializer or a
>   non-native JXON algorithm instead.

```
var response = xmlhttprequest.responseText; // bug 270553
response = response.replace(/^<\?xml\s+version\s*=\s*(["'])[^\1]+\1[^?]*\?>/, ""); // bug 336551
var e4x = new XML(response);
```

I am a bit out of my league here, and have no idea what to do.  Any clue would be appreciated.  How do I use this?

Comment: That doesn't seem like the right line error to me.  Can you share more of your code?  I'm also assuming the validator is the http://addons.mozilla.org/ submission validator.

Comment: Mr. Clark, did you see I added a second line to the "error line"?  Do you have that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was the second line of the code string.

The problem was here (suggested to me by one of the AMO Editors):

```
const XUL = Namespace("xul", "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
```

Defining the constant was what accessed the E4X object.  I never used that constant in any of my code - it was just there because I saw it in the original addon example and just copied it over.

After I removed it, the validator no longer complained.  When I submitted the updated addon, it passed and was duly approved.

Comment: FYI, Here's the documentation for the specific feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion